# How to set max duration record, release a file and start recording automatically using media recorder

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder

My application has a feature that records audio using Media Recorder that is started through a service (IntentService) so that it is recorded in the background.

Because some device and API limitations I need to implement a limit for the files so that once I reach the configured limit, generate the file and start recording again.

Example, upon reaching 1 minute, you must stop recording, generate the file, and start another recording until the service is stopped.

I tryed use setOnInfoListener, but this event is never called, when I defined maxDuration to one minute, after this duration time, the logcat show this message and stop audio record:

Handler (android.media.MediaRecorder$EventHandler) {ee2b629} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.media.MediaRecorder$EventHandler) {ee2b629} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
        at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:545)
        at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:661)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:630)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:600)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:537)
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.postEventFromNative(MediaRecorder.java:1709)

```
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getPath());
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); 
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();

        mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener((mr, what, extra) -> {
            if(what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED){
               //Do somethings
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Start a timer ,which will trigger after a given amount of time, say you want the recording to be max of 20 minutes ,then start timer when you call mediaRecorder.start(), and will trigger after 20 mins calling the stop() and release() method there. You can even cancel if you feel recording is done